# Numbers and wraps for generated divs?

Tags: jquery, css, drupal

I have a drupal generated post table:

```
<div id="row1">text content</div>
<div id="row2">text content</div>
<div id="row3">video content</div>
<div id="row4">video content</div>
<div id="row5">video content</div>
```

The rows changing, but I need to modify the 3 video rows in 1, meaning I need to target these rows without its id, add each a number specific classed wrapper in the row, then I will set their appareance by css (I need to remove the title in video2 and video3 for merging them manually in 1 video post which has 3 video in it, our drupal engine can't do that)

Here's what I need for this:

```
<div id="row1">text content</div>
<div id="row2">text content</div>
<div id="row3"><div class="video1">video content</div></div>
<div id="row4"><div class="video2">video content</div></div>
<div id="row5"><div class="video3">video content</div></div>
```

(the "video content" is 3 different named div, such as date container, article content and post footer, I need to put a wrapper around all of them)

I tried to solve this in jquery, but I can't manage, anyone have a solution for this?

EDIT:

Ok, I'll show you the whole thing. :)

Page 1:

```
<div id="row1">
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content">(article post's text, image, whatever)</div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>

<div id="row2">
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content">(article post's text, image, whatever)</div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>

<div id="row3"> (video1)
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content"><div class="video_image"></div></div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>

<div id="row4"> (video2)
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content"><div class="video_image"></div></div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>

<div id="row5"> (video3)
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content"><div class="video_image"></div></div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>
```

Page 2:

```
<div id="row1">
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content">(article post's text, image, whatever)</div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>

<div id="row2"> (video1)
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content"><div class="video_image"></div></div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>

<div id="row3"> (video2)
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content"><div class="video_image"></div></div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>

<div id="row4"> (video3)
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content"><div class="video_image"></div></div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>

<div id="row5">
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content">(article post's text, image, whatever)</div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>
```

So, the problems:

1: The video containers for each video have same classes, such as "article_content" and "video_image".

2: The rows changing every page, so the "row3" on the first page is a video, on the second is a text article. Basically, we have 5 rows fixed on every page and the content goes in it dynamically.

I think there's a way with jquery to target the "video_image" class, which is the only thing that pointing here's the video content in the page rows, and manage to wrap all above "video_image" to a div called "video1". The other step is to add a count on 1, 2 and 3 video block.

EDIT 2:

The goal is:

```
<div id="row2"> (video1)
<div class="video1">
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content"><div class="video_image"></div></div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="row3"> (video2)
<div class="video2">
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content"><div class="video_image"></div></div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="row4"> (video3)
<div class="video3">
<div class="date_container">(date divs)</div>
<div class="article_content"><div class="video_image"></div></div>
<div class="post_nid">(article footer, with author, etc)</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Or, if the videoX class goes to the row such as

```
<div id="row4" class="video3">...</div>
```

it's good for me also, but as I mentioned before, the row4 can be row1 on the second page of the site.

Comment: Given the two examples of the 'input' ('before-manipulation') HTML, could you also post an 'output' ('after-manipulation') HTML, to demonstrate what you want the DOM to be once manipulation is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, given the updated information:

```
$('.video_image').each(function(i,el){
    $(el).wrap('<div />').parent().attr('class','video' + i);
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jkCR2/).

```
$('.video_image').parent().html(
    function(i,h){
        return '<div class="video' + i + '">' + h + '</div>';
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jkCR2/1/).

The following version goes up to the first element with an `id` and then wraps all its inner html in another `div` with the `videoN` (where N is, obviously, a number):

```
$('.video_image').closest('div[id]').html(function(i,h){
    return '<div class="video' + i + '">' + h + '</div>';
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jkCR2/3/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: This is almost perfect thanks, the only thing that I have to wrap all of the video row, so it contains the "date_container" the "article_content" and the "post_nid". This way I can modify the date and the footer of the videos with css.

Comment: Do you always need the siblings? Or is that conditional..?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#row3').html($('<div class="video3">').html($('#row3').html()));`

Something like that, but I should check for some weak points

EDIT:

if you need to skip first 2 rows:

```
  $('div').each ( function(count) {
     if (count > 1) {
       $(this).html($('<div class="video3">').html($(this).html()));
     }
  });
```

Or may be you need to check if it is a video row or not? Not very clear by the question.

Comment: I feel I should probably remind you of the OP's explicit requirement: *I need to target these rows without [their] `id`*

Comment: @DavidThomas If the requirement is "select `div`s with no `ID`", then the example given by the OP is incorrect.

Comment: Why is his example incorrect? He said he can't select the elements by their `id`, that doesn't preclude the elements *having* an `id`.

Comment: @DavidThomas truth. Then the selector is left unspecified (probably by content; `#content>div:has(object)`, the previous one and the next one?)

Comment: Honestly? Without more context of what he's actually looking for (and I'd be amazed if it's really a string), I'm unsure of how to select. But that approach is probably the better one.

Comment: posted one edit, but it's not very clear what the guy needs to do